# Intellij idea Compilation Error with Project Lombok in JDK-16

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml, lombok

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerargs>
                        <arg>-Werror</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerargs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This my build tag in pom.xml file. But when the run spring boot project, i have exception.
I am using JDK-16 Version. In my intellij idea, installed project lombok as plugin. And i have project lombok dependency. Error is;

```
java: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x48904e01) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x48904e01`
```

Comment: Hi, this issue can be related to https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2681

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But i try it..

Comment: No one should be using packages starting with com.sun.

Comment: okay. I am new in spring boot. What can i do.??? And my spring project start, 'com.fsk'.

i dont know com.sun )):

Comment: It's not your project that uses `com.sun`, it's Lombok.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are using latest lombok version. Then delete .iml file present in the root directory of your project and then do a build should fix this issue.